# Can i use pop3client to download only the newestm essages for example only the 5 newest messages?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Now it's downloading all the messages and i have a lot of them on the server of my internet account. Then after i'm downloading all the messages it will download only the newest messages. But i wonder if i wanted on the first time instead of downloading all the messages to download only the newest 5 messages only ? Or the newest 100 messages only ? And not all the messages on the server.

```
using (var client = new Pop3Client())
                {
                    client.Connect(textServer.Text, Convert.ToInt32(textPort.Text), ssl);
                    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
                    client.Authenticate(textUser.Text, textPassword.Text);

                    var uids = client.GetMessageUids();

                    for (int i = 0; i < client.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
                        {
                            e.Cancel = true;
                            return;
                        }
                        if (!downloaded.Contains(uids[i]))
                        {
                            allMessages.Add(client.GetMessage(i));
                            newmsg = client.GetMessage(i);
                            downloaded.Add(uids[i]);
                            SaveFullMessage(client.GetMessage(i), i);
                            w = new StreamWriter(emailsIDSFile, true);
                            w.WriteLine(uids[i]);
                            w.Close();
                        }

                        int nProgress = (client.Count - i + 1) * 100 / client.Count;
                        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(nProgress,newmsg);//, client.Count.ToString() + "/" + i);
                        newmsg = null;
                    }

                    client.Disconnect(true);
                }
```

I'm getting a List of all the messages Uids:

```
var uids = client.GetMessageUids();
```

And i wonder if i could somehow to do something like in logical: Download only the newest 5 Uids messages or the newest 100 Uids messages. I wonder how and if i can select from the Uids List only the newest 5 or 100 messages to be downloaded.

I don't need and don't care for now about all the messages on the server i want to check only for the N newest messages for example 5 or 100 newest messages.

Comment: You need to cache the ids of each email, check if the id is in the cache, if it is, ignore, otherwise download it, add the id to the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling GetMessageUids, call GetMessageUid multiple times with an increasing message number each time.

See [http://hpop.sourceforge.net/documentation/OpenPop~OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client.GetMessageUid.html]